# GridSearchCV with Invalid parameter gamma for estimator LogisticRegression

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

I need to perform a grid search on the parameters listed below for a Logistic Regression classifier, using recall for scoring and cross-validation three times.

The data is in a csv file (11,1 MB), this link for download is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cQFp7HteaaL37CefsbMNuHqPzkINCVzs/view?usp=sharing

I have `grid_values = {'gamma':[0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}`
I need to apply penalty L1 e L2 in a Logistic Regression

I couldn't verify if the scores will run because I have the following error:
Invalid parameter gamma for estimator LogisticRegression. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('fraud_data.csv')

X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
y = df.iloc[:,-1]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)




def LogisticR_penalty():    
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

    grid_values = {'gamma':[0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}


    #train de model with many parameters for "C" and penalty='l1'
    lr_l1 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
    grid_lr_l1 = GridSearchCV(lr_l1, param_grid = grid_values, cv=3, scoring = 'recall')
    grid_lr_l1.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_decision_fn_scores_recall = grid_lr_l1.decision_function(X_test)


    lr_l2 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2')
    grid_lr_l2 = GridSearchCV(lr_l2, param_grid = grid_values, cv=3 , scoring = 'recall')
    grid_lr_l2.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_decision_fn_scores_recall = grid_lr_l2.decision_function(X_test)



    #The precision, recall, and accuracy scores for every combination 
    #of the parameters in param_grid are stored in cv_results_
    results = pd.DataFrame()

    results['l1_results'] = pd.DataFrame(grid_lr_l1.cv_results_)
    results['l1_results'] = results['l2_results'].sort_values(by='mean_test_precision_score', ascending=False)

    results['l2_results'] = pd.DataFrame(grid_lr_l2.cv_results_)
    results['l2_results'] = results['l2_results'].sort_values(by='mean_test_precision_score', ascending=False)


    return results
LogisticR_penalty()
```

I expected from .cv_results_, the average test scores of each parameter combination that I should be available here: mean_test_precision_score but not sure

The output is: ValueError: Invalid parameter gamma for estimator LogisticRegression. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message contains the answer for your question. You can use the function `estimator.get_params().keys()` to see all available parameters for you estimator:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

lr = LogisticRegression()

print(lr.get_params().keys())
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['C', 'class_weight', 'dual', 'fit_intercept', 'intercept_scaling', 'l1_ratio', 'max_iter', 'multi_class', 'n_jobs', 'penalty', 'random_state', 'solver', 'tol', 'verbose', 'warm_start'])
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me clarify things. I really didn't know you could know all the parameters available to your estimator.

Answer (score 2):

From [scikit-learn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), the `LogisticRegression` has no parameter `gamma`, but a parameter `C` for the regularization weight.

If you change `grid_values = {'gamma':[0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}` for `grid_values = {'C':[0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}` your code should work.

Comment: In addition to changing from gamma to C, I also had to include the penalties I needed to work : grid_values ​​= {'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'], 'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}

Answer (score 0):

My code contained some errors the main error was using param_grid incorrectly. I had to apply L1 and L2 penalties with gamma 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100. The right way to do this is:

```
grid_values ​​= {'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'], 'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}
```

Then it was necessary to correct the way I was training my logistic regression and to correct the way I retrieved the scores in cv_results_ and averaged those scores.
Follow my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('fraud_data.csv')

X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
y = df.iloc[:,-1]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

def LogisticR_penalty():    
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

    grid_values = {'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'], 'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}


    #train de model with many parameters for "C" and penalty='l1'

    lr = LogisticRegression()
    # We use GridSearchCV to find the value of the range that optimizes a given measurement metric.
    grid_lr_recall = GridSearchCV(lr, param_grid = grid_values, cv=3, scoring = 'recall')
    grid_lr_recall.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_decision_fn_scores_recall = grid_lr_recall.decision_function(X_test)

    ##The precision, recall, and accuracy scores for every combination 
    #of the parameters in param_grid are stored in cv_results_
    CVresults = []
    CVresults = pd.DataFrame(grid_lr_recall.cv_results_)

    #test scores and mean of them
    split_test_scores = np.vstack((CVresults['split0_test_score'], CVresults['split1_test_score'], CVresults['split2_test_score']))
    mean_scores = split_test_scores.mean(axis=0).reshape(5, 2)

    return mean_scores
LogisticR_penalty()
```